# Representation of the elements of a normed vector space that has a dense subset.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose that $U$ is a normed vector space and   $S\subset U$ is dense.prove that every element of  $U $ can be written as an absolutely convergent series of the finite linear combination of the  elements of  $S $.

$x\in U$, because  $S  $  is  dense,  we can  write  $x-s_1 \in B_1 (0) $ (the  unit ball centered at $0$), repeatedly $x-(s_1+\ldots +s_n)\in \cap_1^n B_{1/n} (s_{n-1})$.

But how to prove the statement? 
I mean the Absolute convergence.

Thanx a lot

Comment: Maybe get a little closer than $\frac 1n$?

Comment: As B. S. Thompson said, you may want the difference at the $n$-th step to be in a ball centered in $0$ whose radius is **way** smaller than $\frac1n$, because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n=+\infty$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli ok instead of $1/n$,i put $1/n^2$.but what then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an arbitrary $x\in U$ as the limit of a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $S$ such that $|x_n-x|<\frac1{n^2}.$ Then $|x_n-x_{n-1}|<\frac2{n^2}$ and the series

$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x_n-x_{n-1})$$

converges absolutely.

Comment: Thanks! You are very kind!