# the space of lipschitz function is complete with respect to some norm

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be the space of real valued lipschitz functions over $[a,b]$,we define:

$M_f=sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}$

and lipschitz norm:

$||f||_{Lip}=|f(a)|+M_f$

prove that $V$ with lipschitz norm is a complete normed vector space.

it is easy to see $V$ is a vector space,but what about the completeness?

is there any hint?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start from a hypothetical Cauchy sequence of functions (Cauchy in the sense of the newly defined norm). Prove that the values of that function at the left end $a$ converge as real numbers, and then prove that the functions converge pointwise at any $x\in[a,b].$ This allows you to write $f(x)$ for the pointwise limit. Now establish that the sequence actually converges to $f$ in the sense of the new norm.

Explicitly, let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Pick $N$ such that for $m,n\geq N,$ $M_{f_m-f_n}<\epsilon/4.$

For every $x,y\in[a,b]$ choose $m_{x,y}\geq N$ such that $|f_{m_{x,y}}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon|x-y|/4$ and $|f_{m_{x,y}}(y)-f(y)|<\epsilon|x-y|/4.$ Then

$$\eqalign{
\forall x,y\in[a,b]:&|(f(x)-f_n(x))-(f(y)-f_n(y))|\\
&\leq |f(x)-f_{m_{x,y}}(x)|+|f_{m_{x,y}}(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(y)-f_{m_{x,y}}(y)|
+|f_{m_{x,y}}(y)-f(y)| \\
&\leq \epsilon|x-y|.
}$$

Comment: I showed for every  $x $ $f_n (x)$ is cauchy,  so the limit is function  $g $,now I must say  g is the limit  of  $f_n$'s with lip norm.isn't it  true?

Comment: It doesn't! I only needed pointwise convergence to be able to legitimately write the expression $f(x).$ Convergence in the Lipschitz norm follows from the Cauchy nature of the sequence.

Comment: sorry if I don't understand you,but how "Convergence in the Lipschitz norm follows from the Cauchy nature of the sequence."?

Comment: would  you  please  have a look at this?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569194/representation-of-the-elements-of-a-normed-vector-space-that-has-a-dense-subset?noredirect=1#comment3195391_1569194